# How to style angular material select

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'd like to style a select component from Angular Material. Specifically I want to move the panel that contains the options down below the field that shows the selected value.

This list of options is inside a div with id "cdk-overlay..." which seems to decide the positioning of the list. This div is styled with a element.style attribute, which I cannot override with css.

Presumably this style attribute is still based on some css on a lower level. Where is it? How do I change it? Where is it documented?

[You can see what I am talking about in action on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urvaf8-aisk6k)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Angular Material v6, you can apply:

```
<mat-select panelClass="options" disableOptionCentering ...></mat-select>
```

`.options` will be the div **inside** your cdk-overlay element.
Then in your CSS you can add something like:

```
.options {
   margin-top: 2em;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the stackbiltz example provided...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can override properties of a css class by redefining it in your component stylesheet and breaking view encapsulation.

your-component.scss

```
.class-to-override {
    color: white
}
```

your-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@component({
    ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Breaking view encapsulation is not really an option. The style in question are also not in a css class, but in an element.style attribute. You can try your solution in stackblitz by following the link I provided.